# MongoDB Agent Openshift Issue

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

We deployed MongoDB Kubernetes Operator and the opsmanager on openshift 4.7 and they are working fine but once we are trying to deploy the mongoDB pod we are getting below error

> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:“Using Kubernetes CA
> file”} {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:“Created symlink:
> /data/journal → /journal”}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:“Downloading a Mongodb
> Agent from https://ops-manager-dev-svc-mtx-db-dev.apps.com}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:“Error while downloading
> the Mongodb agent”} {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:”*
> Trying 10.27.137.46…"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TCP_NODELAY set"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* Connected to
> ops-manager-dev-svc-mtx-db-dev.apps.com (10.27.137.46) port 443 (#0)"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* ALPN, offering h2"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* ALPN, offering
> http/1.1"} {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"*
> successfully set certificate verify locations:"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* CAfile:
> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:" CApath: none"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"} [5 bytes data]"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS
> handshake, Client hello (1):"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"} [512 bytes data]"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS
> handshake, Server hello (2):"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"{ [122 bytes data]"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS
> handshake, [no content] (0):"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"{ [1 bytes data]"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS
> handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"{ [10 bytes data]"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS
> handshake, [no content] (0):"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS
> handshake, Certificate (11):"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"{ [1416 bytes data]"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS
> alert, unknown CA (560):"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"} [2 bytes data]"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* SSL certificate
> problem: self signed certificate"}
> {“logType”:“agent-launcher-script”,“contents”:"* Closing connection
> 0"}

**MongoDB Yaml :**

```
apiVersion: mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDB
metadata:
  name: mtx-mongodb-dev
spec:
  version: 4.4.6
  opsManager:
    configMapRef:
      name: mtx-dev-project-config
  credentials: mtx-dev-orga-api-key
  
  type: Standalone
  persistent: true
  volumes:
    - name: data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mongo-mtx-dev-pvc
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
```

Comment: Seems like you have a certificate issue, as your MongoDB does not trust your self-signed certificate. A workaround could be to specify `allowInvalidCertificates: true` in your MongoDB configuration, but in general it is better to properly set up your certificates.

Comment: I should apply the certificate on the route of opsmanger in openshift or apply it only on mongodb?